# Android HttpGet android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, json

Im having trouble running the HttpGet, I can access the site with the broswer of the emulator,
but when I try to run my application I get these errors.

```
12-15 05:34:20.573    1702-1702/com.albertoortega.flordemaria E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
            at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.albertoortega.flordemaria.Objects.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:65)
            at com.albertoortega.flordemaria.ActivityLogin$GetLogin$1.run(ActivityLogin.java:98)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the actual code.

```
new GetLogin().execute();

class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityLogin.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Iniciando Sesion. Porfavor espera...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int success;
                    try {
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_USERNAME, user));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PASSWORD, pass));

                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET", params);

                        Log.d("Login", json.toString());

                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OBJECT);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                            user = jsonObject.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                            pass = jsonObject.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
                            accs = jsonObject.getString(TAG_ACCESS);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(ActivityLogin.this, json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

And the class JSONParser

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `runOnUiThread()` in `doInBackground()` completely defeats the purpose of an AsyncTask.

Comment: @MikeM. There you gom Thanks I didnt noticed it was there..

Comment: Do blocking operations in doInBackground() when doInBackground() returns update UI on onPostExecute();

Comment: Guys, apparently @Adem does not understand this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exception is clear from the Logs.

Remove `"runOnUiThread"` from `doInBackground()`.

Network operations must be done in the Background Thread.

Comment: thanks, I didnt noticed that the runOnUiThread was there, I got this stuff from a tutorial. Acepting the answer in 8 mintues.

Comment: @Betoo never use code you don't understand. That you state "you didn't know" shows that you didn't try to understand in the first place.