# ZeroMQ On Android Java ( Android Studio )

Tags: java, android, zeromq, jeromq

I'm trying to program ZeroMQ on my android device and I know how to use ZeroMQ (From C++, Php, .Net , I'm all the time using it.) If I list what I've done until now :

- From Dependencies in Android Studio, I added **org.zeromq:jeromq:0.3.5** from maven central search.
- After that, I put a code like the following :

```
try
{
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

    //  Socket to talk to server
    System.out.println("Connecting to hello world server...");

    ZMQ.Socket requester = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    requester.connect("tcp://192.168.2.127:5555");

    for (int requestNbr = 0; requestNbr != 10; requestNbr++) {
        String request = "Hello";
        System.out.println("Sending Hello " + requestNbr);
        requester.send(request.getBytes(), 0);

        byte[] reply = requester.recv(0);
        System.out.println("Received " + new String(reply) + " " + requestNbr);
    }
    requester.close();
    context.term();


}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Log.e("Error", "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**When I run this, I got an exception like the following :**

```
01-03 02:20:55.200 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.200 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.200 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.210 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.220 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.230 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.230 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.240 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.250 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.260 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:20:55.270 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method mia.face.id.zeromq.MainActivity.access$super
01-03 02:21:08.080 12562-12562/mia.face.id.zeromq E/Error: Exception : null
```

I'm actually not new in programming but in Android/Java stuffs. I cannot figure it out how to solve this problem. I searched on the internet however couldnt find something.

If you can help me, I'll be very pleased.

Thanks in advance.

### (Addtion, I forget to include this one : )

```
01-03 03:12:58.430 1374-1374/mia.face.id.zmqtestest E/Error: Exception
                                                         android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:168)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:490)
                                                             at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.writeImpl(SocketChannelImpl.java:391)
                                                             at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:349)
                                                             at java.nio.PipeImpl$PipeSinkChannel.write(PipeImpl.java:114)
                                                             at zmq.Signaler.send(Signaler.java:121)
                                                             at zmq.Mailbox.send(Mailbox.java:85)
                                                             at zmq.Ctx.sendCommand(Ctx.java:388)
                                                             at zmq.ZObject.sendCommand(ZObject.java:362)
                                                             at zmq.ZObject.sendPlug(ZObject.java:171)
                                                             at zmq.ZObject.sendPlug(ZObject.java:161)
                                                             at zmq.Own.launchChild(Own.java:126)
                                                             at zmq.SocketBase.addEndpoint(SocketBase.java:550)
                                                             at zmq.SocketBase.connect(SocketBase.java:542)
                                                             at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.connect(ZMQ.java:1246)
                                                             at mia.face.id.zmqtestest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android HttpGet android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478608/android-httpget-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

From here, I found the answer, actually the methodology which is about network operation should be in background task.

Maybe this will help for others to shorten the time they are spending for research.

Regards.